# Wait for a number of events before continuing (threadsafe)

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

I have an integration test, where I trigger things by sending off an event. Then a couple of asynchronous things happen, and I expect a specific number of events to be raised by this.

My test code shall wait until this number of events were raised. I did this with a callback subscription to this event and a wait handle. Basically

```
private AutoResetEvent thingsChangedEventOccurred = new AutoResetEvent(false);

private void OnThingsChangedEventOccurred(ThingsChangedEventData thingsChangedEventData)
{
this.thingsChangedEventOccurred.Set();
}

private void WaitForThisNumberOfThingsChangedEvents(int numberOfEventsToWaitFor)
{
    for (int eventsCaptured = 0; eventsCaptured < numberOfEventsToWaitFor; eventsCaptured++)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(this.thingsChangedEventOccurred.WaitOne(60000));
    }
}
```

And somewhere after I sent off the events that start things I call the WaitFor.. Method.
I realize now that this implementation has its problems with threading. I assume the AutoResetEvent can only count to one. Any ideas or patterns on how to make this thread safe? 
I thought about making the eventsCaptured a field... butwell, that is kind of uncool for other reasons.

Comment: did you consider the use of Semaphore

Comment: hmm.. can you elaborate on how to do this? Semaphore seems to count UP not down with the WaitOne() method.. - where AutoResetEvent counts down, kind of. So I end up with the same problems.

Comment: Consider using `CountdownEvent`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [CountdownEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent.aspx).

Basically, you initialize a `CountdownEvent` with the number of events you're expecting. Then, as each event occurs, the code signals the `CountdownEvent`, which will become set after it's been signaled the expected number of times.

It's a pretty handy thing. Definitely check it out.